# How to show visitors' country automatically in an HTML dropdown?

Tags: html, json, forms

I am a digital marketer and newbie to programming. I just want to automatically display the website visitor's country as the selected item in an html dropdown as per their ip address. I tried this code but it fails to show the country as per my concern. Please help me. Here's the url where I want to show the result : https://onlinecharterschool.org/inquire-now/

DEMO: https://coliff.github.io/geoip-db-country-select/

Here's the code which I have used.

```
<div class="inquire-now-block-two-half">
<div class="inquire-page-each-field-label">COUNTRY*</div>
<div class="inquire-query-each-field">
<div class="inquire-query-left-field">
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').val(location.country_name).attr('selected',true);
            populateStates("country", "state");
    }
});
</script>
<select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" selected="selected" autocomplete="country-name">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">Please Select</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="AL">Albania</option><option value="DZ">Algeria</option><option value="AS">American Samoa</option><option value="AD">Andorra</option><option value="AO">Angola</option><option value="AI">Anguilla</option><option value="AQ">Antarctica</option><option value="AG">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option><option value="AR">Argentina</option><option value="AM">Armenia</option><option value="AW">Aruba</option><option value="AC">Ascension Island</option><option value="AU">Australia</option><option value="AT">Austria</option><option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option><option value="BS">Bahamas</option><option value="BH">Bahrain</option><option value="BD">Bangladesh</option><option value="BB">Barbados</option><option value="BY">Belarus</option><option value="BE">Belgium</option><option value="BZ">Belize</option><option value="BJ">Benin</option><option value="BM">Bermuda</option><option value="BT">Bhutan</option><option value="BO">Bolivia</option><option value="BA">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option><option value="BW">Botswana</option><option value="BR">Brazil</option><option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option><option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option><option value="BN">Brunei</option><option value="BG">Bulgaria</option><option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option><option value="BI">Burundi</option><option value="KH">Cambodia</option><option value="CM">Cameroon</option><option value="CA">Canada</option><option value="IC">Canary Islands</option><option value="CV">Cape Verde</option><option value="BQ">Caribbean Netherlands</option><option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option><option value="CF">Central African Republic</option><option value="EA">Ceuta &amp; Melilla</option><option value="TD">Chad</option><option value="CL">Chile</option><option value="CN">China</option><option value="CX">Christmas Island</option><option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option><option value="CO">Colombia</option><option value="KM">Comoros</option><option value="CG">Congo - Brazzaville</option><option value="CD">Congo - Kinshasa</option><option value="CK">Cook Islands</option><option value="CR">Costa Rica</option><option value="CI">Côte d’Ivoire</option><option value="HR">Croatia</option><option value="CU">Cuba</option><option value="CW">Curaçao</option><option value="CY">Cyprus</option><option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option><option value="DK">Denmark</option><option value="DG">Diego Garcia</option><option value="DJ">Djibouti</option><option value="DM">Dominica</option><option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option><option value="EC">Ecuador</option><option value="EG">Egypt</option><option value="SV">El Salvador</option><option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="ER">Eritrea</option><option value="EE">Estonia</option><option value="ET">Ethiopia</option><option value="FK">Falkland Islands</option><option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option><option value="FJ">Fiji</option><option value="FI">Finland</option><option value="FR">France</option><option value="GF">French Guiana</option><option value="PF">French Polynesia</option><option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option><option value="GA">Gabon</option><option value="GM">Gambia</option><option value="GE">Georgia</option><option value="DE">Germany</option><option value="GH">Ghana</option><option value="GI">Gibraltar</option><option value="GR">Greece</option><option value="GL">Greenland</option><option value="GD">Grenada</option><option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option><option value="GU">Guam</option><option value="GT">Guatemala</option><option value="GG">Guernsey</option><option value="GN">Guinea</option><option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option><option value="GY">Guyana</option><option value="HT">Haiti</option><option value="HN">Honduras</option><option value="HK">Hong Kong SAR China</option><option value="HU">Hungary</option><option value="IS">Iceland</option><option value="IN">India</option><option value="ID">Indonesia</option><option value="IR">Iran</option><option value="IQ">Iraq</option><option value="IE">Ireland</option><option value="IM">Isle of Man</option><option value="IL">Israel</option><option value="IT">Italy</option><option value="JM">Jamaica</option><option value="JP">Japan</option><option value="JE">Jersey</option><option value="JO">Jordan</option><option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option><option value="KE">Kenya</option><option value="KI">Kiribati</option><option value="XK">Kosovo</option><option value="KW">Kuwait</option><option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option><option value="LA">Laos</option><option value="LV">Latvia</option><option value="LB">Lebanon</option><option value="LS">Lesotho</option><option value="LR">Liberia</option><option value="LY">Libya</option><option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option><option value="LT">Lithuania</option><option value="LU">Luxembourg</option><option value="MO">Macau SAR China</option><option value="MK">Macedonia</option><option value="MG">Madagascar</option><option value="MW">Malawi</option><option value="MY">Malaysia</option><option value="MV">Maldives</option><option value="ML">Mali</option><option value="MT">Malta</option><option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option><option value="MQ">Martinique</option><option value="MR">Mauritania</option><option value="MU">Mauritius</option><option value="YT">Mayotte</option><option value="MX">Mexico</option><option value="FM">Micronesia</option><option value="MD">Moldova</option><option value="MC">Monaco</option><option value="MN">Mongolia</option><option value="ME">Montenegro</option><option value="MS">Montserrat</option><option value="MA">Morocco</option><option value="MZ">Mozambique</option><option value="MM">Myanmar (Burma)</option><option value="NA">Namibia</option><option value="NR">Nauru</option><option value="NP">Nepal</option><option value="NL">Netherlands</option><option value="NC">New Caledonia</option><option value="NZ">New Zealand</option><option value="NI">Nicaragua</option><option value="NE">Niger</option><option value="NG">Nigeria</option><option value="NU">Niue</option><option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option><option value="KP">North Korea</option><option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option><option value="NO">Norway</option><option value="OM">Oman</option><option value="PK">Pakistan</option><option value="PW">Palau</option><option value="PS">Palestinian Territories</option><option value="PA">Panama</option><option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option><option value="PY">Paraguay</option><option value="PE">Peru</option><option value="PH">Philippines</option><option value="PN">Pitcairn Islands</option><option value="PL">Poland</option><option value="PT">Portugal</option><option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option><option value="QA">Qatar</option><option value="RE">Réunion</option><option value="RO">Romania</option><option value="RU">Russia</option><option value="RW">Rwanda</option><option value="WS">Samoa</option><option value="SM">San Marino</option><option value="ST">São Tomé &amp; Príncipe</option><option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="SN">Senegal</option><option value="RS">Serbia</option><option value="SC">Seychelles</option><option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option><option value="SG">Singapore</option><option value="SX">Sint Maarten</option><option value="SK">Slovakia</option><option value="SI">Slovenia</option><option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option><option value="SO">Somalia</option><option value="ZA">South Africa</option><option value="GS">South Georgia &amp; South Sandwich Islands</option><option value="KR">South Korea</option><option value="SS">South Sudan</option><option value="ES">Spain</option><option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option><option value="BL">St. Barthélemy</option><option value="SH">St. Helena</option><option value="KN">St. Kitts &amp; Nevis</option><option value="LC">St. Lucia</option><option value="MF">St. Martin</option><option value="PM">St. Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option><option value="VC">St. Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option><option value="SD">Sudan</option><option value="SR">Suriname</option><option value="SJ">Svalbard &amp; Jan Mayen</option><option value="SZ">Swaziland</option><option value="SE">Sweden</option><option value="CH">Switzerland</option><option value="SY">Syria</option><option value="TW">Taiwan</option><option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option><option value="TZ">Tanzania</option><option value="TH">Thailand</option><option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option><option value="TG">Togo</option><option value="TK">Tokelau</option><option value="TO">Tonga</option><option value="TT">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option><option value="TA">Tristan da Cunha</option><option value="TN">Tunisia</option><option value="TR">Turkey</option><option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option><option value="TC">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands</option><option value="TV">Tuvalu</option><option value="UM">U.S. Outlying Islands</option><option value="VI">U.S. Virgin Islands</option><option value="UG">Uganda</option><option value="UA">Ukraine</option><option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option><option value="GB">United Kingdom</option><option value="US">United States</option><option value="UY">Uruguay</option><option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option><option value="VU">Vanuatu</option><option value="VA">Vatican City</option><option value="VE">Venezuela</option><option value="VN">Vietnam</option><option value="WF">Wallis &amp; Futuna</option><option value="EH">Western Sahara</option><option value="YE">Yemen</option><option value="ZM">Zambia</option><option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: You should be using the country_code instead of the country_name while handling the AJAX response. When using JS to manipulate select field, the "value" attribute, such as AF, AX and AL, is used for referencing, and not the inner HTML, such as Afghanistan.

Comment: Actually the page doesn't shows required result for US, UK, Argentina and some other places etc. But India, Singapore etc are showing properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.country_code` instead of `location.country_name` in the AJAX response handler.

When using JavaScript to manipulate a HTML `select` tag, the `value` attribute, such as "AF", "AX" and "AL", is used for referencing, and not the inner HTML, such as "Afghanistan".

```js
...
$.ajax({
    url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').val(location.country_code).attr('selected',true);
            populateStates("country", "state");
    }
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, it's not displaying any values as the selected item.

Comment: It worked for me when I tried it in my machine. I believe you made that small change of changing `location.country_name` to `location.country_code` while keeping the rest intact.

Comment: Yes I changed that and here https://onlinecharterschool.org/inquire-now/ it doesn't work for some places like united states

Comment: Ensure that the country_code output from "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp" is the same as the value of the option that represents United States. Please verify the same for all locations.